# arcgis javascript api Rendering some parts of the Featurelayer?

Tags: javascript, api, arcgis, arcgis-server

Hi I'm confused how to render only some parts of a feature layer. Since all the given classbreak rendering samples are rendering the whole feature layer, is there any method to render only a few of the polygons in the feature layer (already have the Object IDs). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional way is by calling [`setDefinitionExpression()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer.html#setdefinitionexpression) on the FeatureLayer, assuming there is a distinct property of the features you want to display. If you already have the OIDs, and there's no distinct property, you could set the expression to `OID = 1 OR OID = 2 OR OID = 3...`, but that might get messy in a hurry.

I think you might also be able to do it using the ClassBreaksRenderer and setting the other symbols to `null`...?